# using equal() method on two different objects with same attribute

Tags: java

Say I have two Classes `A` & `B` with no relationship between them and both have the same attribute `private int _x`

then I set the following method for `A`:

```
public boolean equals (A other) {
    return ((other!=null) && ( _x == other._x));
}
```

and `B` :

```
public boolean equals (Object other) {
    return ((other!=null) && (other instanceof B) && (_x = ((B)other._x));
}
```

Now if I apply the following

```
B z1 = new B(10);
Object z2 = new A(10);

System.out.print(z1.equals((A)z2);
```

I would expect to get `true` as the compiler decide which method to run according to the type of the **object** inserted(!) and not the **pointer** .

I know this website is less about theory but if someone could just comment and tell me why I get `false` running this code?

Comment: An A isn't a B, so `(other instanceof B)` will be `false`.

Comment: Because `z2` is not an instance of `B`. As a side note, `instanceof` will already return `false` if the left operand is `null`, so the manual null-check is superfluous.

Comment: The actual name of attribute `_x` on `A` class is `packagename.A._x`. Same for `B`. (It's not actually like that, but close to). That means that unless `A` knows about `B` class, it can't access its properties, because it would try to access `A._x`, not `B._x`, and it will fail to do so. What you're trying to do is called Duck Typing. Java doesn't support Duck Typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.print(z1.equals((A)z2);
```

This prints `false` because `other instanceof B` evaluates to `false` in B#equals implementation:

```
public boolean equals (Object other) {
    return ((other!=null) && (other instanceof B) && (_x = ((B)other._x));
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: but doesn't java run the method of the **inserted** object?

Comment: `equals` is invoked on the object referred by `z1`, which is of type `B`.

Comment: @bm1125 no: **object_which_calls . method_of_that_object**

Comment: @Passi does it hold even if A inherits from B and a1 = A() b1 = B() and then I call b1.someMethod(a1) . Will it run the method of A or B??

Comment: @bm1125 b1, which calls someMethod is **just of type B** (base class). b1 **does not know there are any subclasses** of its class and just calls the implementation of someMethod of class B.